# Regex to match URL except for some websites using Look Ahead

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to create a regex to filter out url except for some websites.

```
(?!(.*mysite))((www|http|.*com).*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/Su5zlB/9

My struggle is with excluding certain websites. I have tried look ahead but it doesn't seem to work. I expect it to behave like an AND operation so it should not proceed to next condition if first one is false. Any ideas?

Comment: can you add an example ? I'm not exactly clear on your 'AND' behavior

Comment: `^(https?:\/\/)?(?!mysite)([-\w]+\.)(?!mysite).*$` This pattern can help to figure out the url without `mysite`. But it still cannot get the link for the case `sdsd sd https://www.youtube.com`. I hope you can find some thing useful from it. https://regex101.com/r/Su5zlB/18

Comment: Why not simply exclude the set of websites that should not match externally to the regex? `if X in Y then skip`

Comment: What are the requirements? Site should not contain `mysite` anywhere, or just inside `[PROTOCOL]://mysite.com`? What about those `www`, `http` and `.com`? If you just want to require a URL to have `http`, `www` and `com` in it, but not `mysite` host, then it seems you may use [`preg_match('~^https?://(?:[^./]+\.)*(?!mysite)[^./]+\.com(?:/.*)?$~', $url)`](https://regex101.com/r/nH37HJ/1)

Comment: @ti7 I did that programatically and got it to work. I was just wondering if there is a single regex that could solve my problem

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your regex works thanks

Comment: @KarloSerrano: Posted as an answer with explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to require a URL to have `http`, `www` and `com` in it, but not `mysite` in the host part, then you may use

```
preg_match('~^https?://(?:[^./]+\.)*(?!mysite)[^./]+\.com(?:‌​/.*)?$~', $url)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nH37HJ/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `https?://` - `http://` or `https://`
- `(?:[^./]+\.)*`  - zero or more sequences of:

  - `[^./]+`  - 1+ chars other than `.` and `/`
  - `\.` - a literal dot
- `(?!mysite)[^./]+` - 1+ chars other than `.` and `/` that - up to `.com` - does not equal `mysite`
- `\.com` - a `.com` string
- `(?:‌​/.*)?` - 1 or 0 sequences of

  - `/` - slash
  - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).